# JavaFX, external class extends pane, adding that to main class doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx

JavaFX main class:

```
public class Test1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

       Pane sp = new Pane();
       SubClass sc = new SubClass();
       sc.c.setFill(Color.AQUA);
       sp.getChildren().add(sc);
       Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 250, 250);
       stage.setTitle("Testing");
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here is my another class :

```
public class SubClass extends Pane
{   
   Circle c = new Circle(100.0f,100.0f,100.0f);
}
```

But I don't see my circle appearing anywhere in my output. My output is completely blank. Can somebody point at what am I doing wrong?

Here is my output windows:

[image]

Comment: All your subclass does it create the circle. It doesn't add it to a pane anywhere.

Comment: then how do I add it to the pane that my class is extending? something like `this.getChildren().add(c)` ? @James_D

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your subclass does it create the circle. It doesn't add it to a pane anywhere. To add it to the pane, you need to call `getChildren().add(...)` somewhere; for example in the constructor:

```
public class SubClass extends Pane {   

   Circle c = new Circle(100.0f,100.0f,100.0f);

   public SubClass() {
        getChildren().add(c);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @James_D . Mind telling me why does this command won't work outside the constructor?

Comment: Well it does; it will work in any method. However, if you put it in a different method, then you would need the additional step of calling that method (`sc.whateverYouCallTheMethod();`).

Comment: What if it isn't inside any method?

Comment: How do you mean? How could it not be inside a method? Are you referring to using an initializer block?

Comment: sorry but I am a bit in-experienced and I don't see why it needs to be inside a method

Comment: What would it even mean if it wasn't inside a method? When would you expect it to execute?

Comment: I would expect it to execute the same thing as it did inside a method. for e.g.. I created a circle like this `Circle c = new Circle()` . now will this not work `c.setRadius(100.0f)` ? i.e. outside all methods inside the class or do all of these things need to be inside a method? i.e. can I just declare variables inside a class and not do anything to them?

Comment: That makes no sense. Code inside a method executes when you invoke the method. So how can code outside a method execute "the same thing as it did inside a method"? `c.setRadius(100);` won't even *compile* if it is not inside a method (or an initializer block, which is very advanced, and probably bad practice anyway).

Comment: sorry but I am new to java. switched from c++ and hence skipped most of the basics. did not know that. just to be clear you can only declare variables inside a class and nothing else unless you create a method right?

Comment: As you've seen, you can declare *and initialize* instance variables at the class level. Other executable code needs to be inside a method (here I include constructors as methods).

Comment: I don't know why but this works for this test case that I created but not working in my original program. @James_D would you. care to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288767/javafx-external-class-extends-pane-adding-that-to-main-class-wont-work