# JavaFX, external class extends pane, adding that to main class won't work

Tags: java, css, javafx

here is my main class :

```
public class Digital_Analog_Clock_Beta_1 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        double outerBoxWidth = 500, outerBoxHeight = outerBoxWidth / 2.5;
        Rectangle outerBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, outerBoxWidth, outerBoxHeight);
        outerBox.setId("outer-box");

        Rectangle part1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, outerBoxWidth * .35, outerBoxHeight);
        part1.setId("partition");
        Rectangle part2 = new Rectangle(outerBoxWidth * .35, 0, outerBoxWidth * .05, outerBoxHeight);
        part2.setId("partition-alternate");
        Rectangle part3 = new Rectangle(outerBoxWidth * .4, 0, outerBoxWidth * .35, outerBoxHeight);
        part3.setId("partition");
        Rectangle part4 = new Rectangle(outerBoxWidth * .75, 0, outerBoxWidth * .35, outerBoxHeight);
        part4.setId("partition-alternate");

        double bigNumWidth = outerBoxWidth * .35;
        double digitWidth = (.9 * bigNumWidth / 2) * 0.95;
        double digitHeight = .9*outerBoxHeight;
        
                
        digit Digit1 = new digit(outerBoxWidth*.1,outerBoxHeight*.1,digitWidth,digitHeight);
        Digit1.bottom.setId("digits");
        Digit1.c.setFill(Color.AQUA);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(outerBox);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(part1, part2, part3, part4);
        //pane.setId("background");
        
        pane.getChildren().add(Digit1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, outerBoxWidth, outerBoxHeight);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styleSheet.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setTitle("DIgital Analog Clock Beta 1");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

my digit class :

```
public class digit extends Pane
{

    double startX, startY, digitWidth, digitHeight, lineWidth;

    public digit(double startX, double startY, double digitWidth, double digitHeight)
    {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.digitWidth = digitWidth;
        this.digitHeight = digitHeight;
        lineWidth = digitHeight / 20;
        getChildren().addAll(top,middle,bottom,upperLeft,upperRight,lowerLeft,lowerRight, c);
    }

    Polygon top = new Polygon(startX, startY, startX + digitWidth, startY, startX + digitWidth - lineWidth, startY + lineWidth * .95, startX + lineWidth, startY + lineWidth * .95);
    Polygon middle = new Polygon(startX + lineWidth, startY + digitHeight / 2 - lineWidth / 2 + lineWidth * .05,
            startX + digitWidth - lineWidth, startY + digitHeight / 2 - lineWidth / 2 + lineWidth * .05,
            startX + digitWidth - lineWidth * .05, startY + digitHeight, startX + digitWidth - lineWidth, startY + digitHeight / 2 + lineWidth / 2 - lineWidth * .05,
            startX + lineWidth, startY + digitHeight / 2 + lineWidth / 2 - lineWidth * .05, startX + lineWidth * .05, startY + digitHeight / 2);
    Polygon bottom = new Polygon(startX, startY + digitHeight, startX + digitWidth, startY + digitHeight, startX + digitWidth - lineWidth, startY + digitHeight - lineWidth * .95,
            startX + lineWidth, startY + digitHeight - lineWidth * .95);
    Polygon upperLeft = new Polygon(startX, startY, startX + lineWidth * .95, startY + lineWidth, startX + lineWidth * .95, startY + digitHeight / 2 - lineWidth / 2, startX, startY + digitHeight / 2);
    Polygon lowerLeft = new Polygon(startX, startY + digitHeight / 2, startX + lineWidth * .95, startY + digitHeight / 2 + lineWidth / 2, startX + lineWidth * .95, startY + digitHeight - lineWidth,
            startX, startY + digitHeight);
    Polygon upperRight = new Polygon(startX + digitWidth, startY, startX + digitWidth, startY + digitHeight / 2, startX + digitWidth - lineWidth * .95, startY + digitHeight / 2 - lineWidth / 2,
            startX + digitWidth - lineWidth * .95, startY + lineWidth);
    Polygon lowerRight = new Polygon(startX+digitWidth,startY+digitHeight/2,startX+digitWidth,startY+digitHeight,startX+digitWidth-lineWidth*.95,startY+digitHeight-lineWidth,
            startX+digitWidth-lineWidth*.95,startY+lineWidth/2+digitHeight/2);
    
   Circle c = new Circle(100.0f,100.0f,1000.0f);
    
}
```

styleSheet.css :

```
#outer-box
{
     -fx-fill: #353839; /* Onyx */
}

#outer-box-t
{
    -fx-fill: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* transparent */
}

#partition
{
    -fx-fill: rgba(200,200,205,0.25)  /* #C8C8CD Blue Grey a : 0.5*/
}

#partition-alternate
{
    -fx-fill: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* transparent i.e. Onyx */
}

#background
{
    -fx-background-color: #C53151; /* Dingy Dungeon */
}

#digits
{
    -fx-fill : #66FF66; /* Screamin' Green */   
     -fx-stroke: #C53151; /* Dingy Dungeon */
    -fx-stroke-width : 3;
}
```

my output window :

[image]

my digits are supposed to pop up on top of this background I created. I made these many rectangles in main class just for spacing out my digits according to my needs. you can ignore the part where I create polygons( so I even created a circle at the bottom of my digit.java but nothing from digit.java is visible in my output window. I kind of asked this question over here : [JavaFX, external class extends pane, adding that to main class doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287874/javafx-external-class-extends-pane-adding-that-to-main-class-doesnt-work/45288045?noredirect=1#comment77539277_45288045) and it worked for the test case that I created. no idea what is the problem with this actual program I am working on

**update:**
everything except my circle is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables initialized inline will be initialized *before* the constructor is called, so at the point where, say, `top` is initialized all of `startx`, `starty`, `digitWidth`, `digitHeight`, and `lineWidth` will be zero.

See the [JLS, section 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5):

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

Note that "assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables" (step 4) occurs before "Execute the rest of the body of this constructor" (step 5).

Move the initialization of the polygons to the constructor:

```
public class digit extends Pane {

    double startX, startY, digitWidth, digitHeight, lineWidth;

    Polygon top ;
    Polygon middle ;
    Polygon bottom ;
    Polygon upperLeft ;
    Polygon upperRight ;
    Polygon upperLeft ;
    Polygon lowerLeft ;

    public digit(double startX, double startY, double digitWidth, double digitHeight)
    {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.digitWidth = digitWidth;
        this.digitHeight = digitHeight;
        lineWidth = digitHeight / 20;
        getChildren().addAll(top,middle,bottom,upperLeft,upperRight,lowerLeft,lowerRight, c);
        this.top = new Polygon(startX, startY, startX + digitWidth, startY, startX + digitWidth - lineWidth, startY + lineWidth * .95, startX + lineWidth, startY + lineWidth * .95);

        // etc...
    }

}
```

Comment: I almost forgot to tell you, you are awesome!! You don't know how it feels when someone actually helps you rather than confusing you even more or trying to look down at you.

Comment: @ErwinSmith Not sure everyone would agree with that assessment, but thanks anyway...